# How can I use the get() function to access the HRSA API?

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to access data from data.hrsa.gov using their API described [here.](https://data.hrsa.gov/data/services) I have registered with the website and have saved the token to use in my R script. The website gives some details on the web services endpoints [here.](https://data.hrsa.gov/Content/Documents/data-services/DeveloperGuide.pdf) In my code below, I am trying to access the data from the endpoint https://data.hrsa.gov/HDWAPI3_External/api/v1/GetHealthCentersByArea.

I have tried the following code (with the token suppressed):

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

HRSA_token <- "TOKEN"

HRSA_test <- httr::GET("https://data.hrsa.gov/HDWAPI3_External/api/v1/GetHealthCentersByArea",
                       httr::authenticate(
                         user = Sys.getenv(HRSA_token),
                         password = "",
                         type = "basic"
                       ))
HRSA_test
```

And when viewing the object HRSA_test I get this output in the console:

```
Response [https://data.hrsa.gov/HDWAPI3_External/api/v1/GetHealthCentersByArea]
  Date: 2022-10-13 17:37
  Status: 405
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 72 B
```

I am very much new to using APIs and I am not sure what is causing the error. I know that a successful `GET()` results in a status code of 200. I have tried other endpoint links and have gotten different status codes as well. [This link](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) shows that the code 405 means that:

> "The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource."

What I would like to end up with is a data set that lists each health center and the corresponding details (as listed in the developer documentation).

Can anyone provide further guidance or point me towards the right resource to figure this out? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The developer guide is not great. Have you tried adding in some of the specified query parameters? There is no indication of which are mandatory and which are optional. Perhaps start by playing around with these and examine http response codes.

Answer (score 1):

I had to struggled with the documentation as well.

1. You need to send the it as a post request
2. You send the parameters including your token in the body as `x-www-form-urlencoded`

   ```
   library(httr)

   HRSA_token <- "TOKEN-HERE"

   url <- "https://data.hrsa.gov/HDWAPI3_External/api/v1/GetHealthCentersByArea"

   body_data <- list(
       Token = HRSA_token,
       ZipCode = 14624
   )

   response <- httr::POST(url, body = body_data, encode = "form")

   print(content(response, as = "text"))
   ```